# View why other reviewers rejected the draft

Tags: feature-request, documentation, documentation-drafts

It happened to me a few times that I approve an edit an when I get to see that other person rejected the edit, I read their reason and find it to be truth, so I immediately regret my decision.

To prevent this I almost 100% of the times comment after approving or rejecting giving feedback to the creator of the draft and also my opinion to other reviewers.

**Could we see what reason other reviwers gave to reject the draft?**

If disclosing votes is not an option, maybe automatically adding a comment would be another approach.

Comment: I fully agree with that. It only happened once to me (of a hundreds of reviews), but still, that time I wished there were a comment... Could work well in conjunction with http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/329219/2153758

Comment: Might also be better if others have approved/rejected that you can see that before you make your choice instead of after. Right now it always looks like you are the first one to take action. Suspect a lot of people are uncertain sometimes on some judgement calls and things sit in pending review longer than they might if it was easier to see a consensus

Comment: @charlietfl The problem with that is already existing opinions may affect future ones. I think this was intentional and i agree with it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secret_ballot

Comment: @MarcoScabbiolo considered that myself which is why i qualified it with "might be". One difference here from a typical  vote of only yes/no is those comments as per your situation in question. Voting for government is one thing, but this is supposed to be a collaboration

Comment: @charlietfl I'm not sure whether you should see approval votes [okay, currently not an issue as it's usually just one vote] … but if we ever increase it, seeing an approval vote may subconsciously make you less attentive. For rejection votes however, you look at it and wonder whether you can agree with the rejection vote and then re-read.

Comment: @bwoebi especially for a lot of low rep users that aren't as used to dealing with things like close votes. But collaboration consensus issues are not exclusive to them either